# django is it possible to aggregate all the fields of a queryset at once

Tags: django

Data comes from another database so i cant edit the model.

each user plays several matches and each match's stats are saved on its own table line
for example if i need to count the amount of kills a player made i can count it by

```
kills = Get5StatsPlayers.objects.filter(steamid64=reuest.user.SocialAuth.uid).aggregate(
sum=Sum('kills'))
```

my question is can i do it to all of the fields at once?

```
class Get5StatsPlayers(models.Model):
matchid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
mapnumber = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
steamid64 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
team = models.CharField(max_length=16)
rounds_played = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
kills = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
deaths = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
assists = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
flashbang_assists = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
teamkills = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
headshot_kills = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
damage = models.PositiveIntegerField()
bomb_plants = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
bomb_defuses = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
v1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
v2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
v3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
v4 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
v5 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
number_2k = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_column='2k')  # Field renamed because it wasn't a valid Python identifier.
number_3k = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_column='3k')  # Field renamed because it wasn't a valid Python identifier.
number_4k = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_column='4k')  # Field renamed because it wasn't a valid Python identifier.
number_5k = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_column='5k')  # Field renamed because it wasn't a valid Python identifier.
firstkill_t = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
firstkill_ct = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
firstdeath_t = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
firstdeath_ct = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

You can pass multiple aggregate functions to `.aggregate()` call to get aggregation on multiple columns:

```
stats = Get5StatsPlayers.objects.filter(
    steamid64=request.user.SocialAuth.uid
).aggregate(
    s_kills=Sum('kills'),
    s_deaths=Sum('deaths'),
    s_headshot_kills=Sum('headshot_kills'),
    s_teamkills=Sum('teamkills'),
    # and so on ...
)
```

For more automation you can have list of fields to be aggregated (and store it i.e. as model attribute; or have a method to traverse all model fields, if they are Integer - add them to list) and then aggregate list of fields into dictionary of field names in resulted aggregate call and aggregate function to apply:

```
aggregate_fields = ['kills', 'teamkills', 'headshot_kills']

stats_agg = {}
for field in aggregate_fields:
    stats_agg['sum_%s' % field] = Sum(field)

stats = Get5StatsPlayers.objects.filter(
    steamid64=request.user.SocialAuth.uid
).aggregate(
    **stats_agg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that will dynamically add fields to aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.fields import PositiveIntegerField, PositiveSmallIntegerField

class Get5StatsPlayers(models.Model):
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def aggregate_many(model, qs, exclude=None):
        exclude_fields = exclude if exclude else []
        model_fields = model._met.get_fields()
        int_fields = [field for field in model_fields if isinstance(field, (PositiveIntegerField, PositiveSmallIntegerField)) and field.name not in exclude_fields]
        aggregation_fields = dict([(f'{field.name}_sum', Sum(f'{field.name}')) for field in int_fields])
        return qs.aggregate(**aggregation_fields)
```

And then call this method:

```
aggregated_qs = Get5StatsPlayers.aggregate_many(Get5StatsPlayers, your_queryset)
```

In result, all your integer fields in any model you pass to the function will be automatically added to aggregation.

You can make this even more comfortable to use by moving this to model manager.